# How remove test discover errors for SpecFlow tests?

Tags: mstest, specflow

I started to play with SpecFlow and the SpecFlow+ Runner. Now I want to stick with MsTest v2.

So I removed the SpecFlow runner packages and added SpecFlow.MsTest package to my project. It also contains MsTest.TestAdapter and MsTest.TestFramework.

Test Explorer in Visual Studio shows all tests, and I can also run all of them from there.

But on the Test output panel, I see some errors like:

**Unable to fetch symbols for class: Name of my feature file**

And also:

**Unable to fetch source Information for test method: test method**

Any ideas where these errors are coming from and how to remove them?

Comment: Check the "Build" settings for your tests project. I wonder if those errors are coming from there.

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary. Any specific configuration to look at?

Comment: I have the same problem using NUnit 3.15, VS 2017 v.15.9.3 and Dotnet Extensions for Test Explorer 15.3.0.10. Any news on this problem?

Comment: As fate would have it, I'm upgrading out test projects from SpecFlow 2.4 to 3.0 and using MsBuild test generation. I'm getting the same exact problem. The tests seem to run and pass, but I can no longer set a debug breakpoint in a feature file and have the debugger stop at that line. I even created a brand new solution in Visual Studio 2017 and a fresh Unit Test project (.NET Framework) and have the same problem.

Comment: @AndreasWillich: Any ideas here?

Comment: Looks like a related GitHub issue for SpecFlow: [It is not possible debug using specflow 3](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/1521).

Comment: I actually opened a new GitHub issue: [Getting 'Unable to fetch symbols for class' error in visual studio Tests output when using SpecFlow MSBuild test generation](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/1750).